# Alternative Biomart Hosts

Tags: r, server, bioinformatics, biomart

I am trying to run the following Biomart script

```
(params$species == "rabbit"){
    ensembl = useMart(biomart="ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL",
                  dataset="ocuniculus_gene_ensembl", 
                  host="uswest.ensembl.org",
                  ensemblRedirect = FALSE)
    orgSymbols <- unlist(getBM(attributes = 'ensembl_gene_id', mart=ensembl))
    mart <- useMart(dataset = "ocuniculus_gene_ensembl", biomart='ensembl', host="uswest.ensembl.org")
```

The host  keeps timing out - does anyone know another host URL I could use?

Thank you

Comment: Try running ``listMarts`` and choose one.

Comment: More info [here](https://rdrr.io/bioc/biomaRt/man/listMarts.html).